# Trying to use Linear Optimization to solve inequalities

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, series-expansion, inequalities

I am trying to use Mathematica to get bounds on some quantities using a certain procedure which is called [conformal bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_bootstrap). For the users who don't come with a background in HEP, I am basically trying to solve a lot of inequalities using LinearOptimization.

Using SeriesCoefficients, I am trying to extract the coefficients of a function which is so
defined here:

```
F[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, l_, z_, 
  y_] := ((1 - z)^d (1 - y)^d 1/
      2 (gcb[z, y, \[CapitalDelta], l] + 
       gcb[y, z, \[CapitalDelta], l]) - 
    z^d y^d 1/
      2 (gcb[1 - z, 1 - y, \[CapitalDelta], l] + 
       gcb[1 - y, 1 - z, \[CapitalDelta], l]))/(z^d y^d - (1 - z)^
      d (1 - y)^d)

gcb[z_, y_, \[CapitalDelta]_, 
  l_] := (-1)^l/
   2^l (k[\[CapitalDelta] + l, z] k[\[CapitalDelta] - l, y] + 
    k[\[CapitalDelta] + l, y] k[\[CapitalDelta] - l, z])

k[\[Beta]_, x_] := 
 x^(\[Beta]/2) Hypergeometric2F1[\[Beta]/2, \[Beta]/2, \[Beta], x]

seriesF[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, 
   l_] = (Series[
       F[d, \[CapitalDelta], l, z, y] /. {a -> \[Epsilon] a, 
         b -> \[Epsilon] b}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 6}] // Simplify // 
     Normal) /. {\[Epsilon] -> 1};
```

With the variable definitions

```
z := 1/2 + a + b
y := 1/2 + a - b
```

Notice the `=` instead of the `:=` in the definition of the function `seriesF`. That was suggested by a friend saying that it would make the code faster as `Mathematica` will evaluate things once and for all. I do not know if that works and when I do not use delayed assignment my code takes forever to run (in fact it has never ended running so far as much as I have tried). Delayed assignment, however, works.

What this piece of code does is that, using the substitutions of `z` and `y`, I get a series with the coefficients of the function `F` with coefficients as its derivatives at `a = b = 0`. But this entire process is slow since the variable `\CapitalDelta` is supposed to run from a very small value, say, 0.001 to values as big as 80 with steps of 0.01. Similar `l` can also take a large number of values running from `l = 0` to `l = 24` in steps of 2. This is causing my code to run very slow.

I think this is a very hyperspecialized question and it is difficult to explain what I am trying to do. But I will try and explain it as a numerical problem. After running the above code I obtain the $(m, n)$ derivatives of $F$ with respect to $z, y$. Then what I have to do is I have a set of inequalities in variables $a_{mn}$which I have to find solution for (in fixed $d$):

[image]

(Stackexchange is not letting me post LaTex) I use `LinearOptimization` with $0$ as the function to optimize for this problem. Then if there is a solution I increase $\Delta_\text{min}$ until there is none. If there is no solution then I decrease $\Delta_\text{min}$ until there is one. This entire process is taking a lot of time and I am looking for ways to make it more efficient. Could you please help me? Thanks. Sorry for the bad formatting it is my first time posting here.

Comment: Can you use binary search or bigger steps at first like in simulated annealing for Delta?